# Facebook canvas - Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I have a Facebook app where I added two platform: Android and iOS. Now we also added the canvas platform but when we try to use the provided url (https://apps.facebook.com/XXX) we have the following error: Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration...
I read plenty of discussions here in stackoverflow but I still can't fix the problem.

[image]

The APP DOMAIN and the SECURE CANVAS URL are exactly the same a part for the final /fb/ which is the directory containing the html we want to render. I also tried with different APP DOMAIN:

- www.example.com
- http://example.com
- using a blank APP DOMAIN

but with the same result.
The funny thing is that we tried to create a new app from scratch with the same configuration (but without the Android and iOS platforms) and it works perfectly.

Any idea?!

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to call the login dialog automatically when the user enters your canvas URL? If so, you need to specify a Valid OAuth Redirect URI in the advanced settings section.

Comment: It worked!! Many thanks, that was the problem.